# Imprimir en un pdf datos de un select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf

Tengo una tabla scaffold donde ingreso clientes, tengo un select donde mis option los consulto con un each do, lo selecciono y lo imprimo con un javascript, quiero que esos datos sean los unicos que se filtren a mi pdf como encabezado.

Consulta

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  function mostrarValor(select) {
    select.parentNode.querySelector("input[name=remision]").value = select.value;
  }
</script>

<center>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <select class="custom-select" name="sel_remision" id="sel_remision" onChange="mostrarValor(this)">>
    <option selected>Selecciona cliente</option>
      <% @clienteremis.each do |clienteremi|%>
      <option value="<%= clienteremi.nombre %><%= clienteremi.apellidos %>
      <%= clienteremi.empresa %>
      <%= clienteremi.nit %>
      <%= clienteremi.ciudad %>
      <%= clienteremi.direccion %>
      <%= clienteremi.telefono %>
      <%= clienteremi.forma_pago %>">
      <%= clienteremi.nombre %>&nbsp;<%= clienteremi.apellidos %></option>
    <% end %>
  </select>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="remision" class="form-control" value="Datos cliente" />
  <input type="hidden" name="remision" class="form-control" value="Datos cliente" />
  <hr>
</div>
</center>
<br>
<br>
```

controller

```
def index
  @clienteremis = Clienteremi.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json
    format.pdf do
        render template: "remisiones/pdfRemi", pdf: 'Pdf'
    end
  end
end
```

pdf

```
<% @clienteremis.each do |clienteremi|%>
          <b>Nombre :&nbsp;</b><%= clienteremi.nombre %>&nbsp;<%= clienteremi.apellidos %>
          <b>Empresa :</b><%= clienteremi.empresa %>
          <b>Nit/C.c :</b><%= clienteremi.nit %>
          <b>Ciudad : </b><%= clienteremi.ciudad %>
          <b>Direccion :</b><%= clienteremi.direccion %>
          <b>Tel o Cel : </b><%= clienteremi.telefono %>
          <b>Forma de pago : </b><%= clienteremi.forma_pago %>
          <b>Vendedor : </b>Null
          <center>
          <b>Nº Orden/Pedido : &nbsp;</b>Null
          </center>
        <% end %>
```

Comment: Hola Stiven, bienvenido a S.O. No entiendo tu pregunta. Por lo que veo en la última parte, ya estás generando el pdf y estás imprimiendo los valores de `Clienteremi` ¿eso no te funciona? ¿estás tratando de imprimir, pero no te los genera? ¿qué gema estás usando para generar los pdf?

Comment: Hola, bueno mira el si esta imprimiendo, pero me imprime todos los registros de mi tabla en mi pdf, mis 10 clientes, yo quiero que con el select se seleccione 1 y ese sea el unico que aparezca en mi pdf, gema wicked_pdf

Comment: Entonces tu problema no está en que no puedas generar tu pdf, sino que no estás guardando adecuadamente la asociación, si no me equivoco. Creo que deberías repasar el cómo [crear formularios](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) porque como lo estás haciendo no es la "rails way". Deberías estar usando los helpers `form_for` y `select` si estás trabajando con erb, a menos que tengas una muy buena razón para no hacerlo. De hecho eso que estás haciendo de poner todos los campos de clienteremi en el value de los options según mi punto de vista está mal, deberías poner solo el id.

Comment: Aun sigo teniendo problemas, mi problema esta en hacer un select que tenga los datos de mi tabla scaffold y que esos datos seleccionados sean los unicos que se muestren en mi pdf, no se como hacerlo eh intentado miles de formas